# How would I make this image background come out for only half of the section?

Tags: html, css, debugging

I'm working on a website and in a particular section, I want a blue background image to appear for half the section but no matter what I do in terms of CSS, absolutely nothing works.

I've made so many attempts that it's too many to list.  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's my html code:

```
<div class="row secOne secT">
    <div class="myImage col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

Here's my css code:

```
.row.secOne.secT {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.myImage {
   background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/281260/pexels-photo-281260.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: `background-size:50% 100%` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif haha, I've tried that already.  but it doesn't work :(

Comment: and you have set `no-repeat`?

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to understand what you want, is it something like so ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: @TemaniAfif yep, still doesn't work.

Comment: `so many attempts that it's too many to list.` --> we only need at least one to correct you

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, and my attempt in my css is listed above :)

Comment: it should work : https://jsfiddle.net/Leymxb4u/

Comment: @Countingstuff yep!

Comment: you are using cover .. so you didn't specify anything to make it half the section

Answer (score 1):

I've tried creating a simple html file using your code and by applying

```
background-size: 50% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

on the item having the desired image background I got something that seems your desired result.

---

Full code sample

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .col-md-6 {   /* Added this definition in order to get a visible div */
      width: 800px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .row.secOne.secT {
      padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .myImage {
      background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/281260/pexels-photo-281260.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
      -webkit-background-size: 50% 100%;
      -moz-background-size: 50% 100%;
      -o-background-size: 50% 100%;;
      background-size: 50% 100%; /* Force background size to only fill half the div */
      background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Avoid background repetitions */
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row secOne secT">
        <div class="myImage col-md-6">
          AAAAA
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image: The result]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdk00.png
Try this too - https://i.stack.imgur.com/meURR.png

I hope it helps you - sorry if it does not.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include the code in your answer instead of attaching an image. It will be more accessible for people looking at it.

Answer (score -1):

You can make appear the blue background of your URL, setting the height CSS property

```css
.row.secOne.secT {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.myImage {
   background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/281260/pexels-photo-281260.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 22em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row secOne secT">
    <div class="myImage col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!